# Mysql Schedule Events

Tags: mysql, cron, scheduled-tasks

I'm learning some Mysql and I have this question:
In my db when someone puts an item in the cart it gets "reserved" state. But if the person does not checkout in the next 30 min, the item should be set to "free" again. Is it possible to make without using CRON ?
Or some lightweight solution....

Thank you!  :)

Comment: hmmm negative vote with no answer? that's new

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to set reserved to a specific time, say:

```
update `item` set `reserved` = 1, `reservedto` = ADDTIME(NOW(),'00:30') where `id` = ?;
```

Then before checking available items (or someplace else if that happens to often) just add a realese statement like so:

```
update `item` set `reserved` = 0 where `reservedto` < NOW() and `reserved` = 1;
```

If you have a large table you might want to put an index on reservedto column.

Comment: the table is expected to be quite big... that query will be kind of heavy won't it ?

Comment: Yes, the second command will be heavy and should not be executed to often. Your alternative would be to create a second table with just reservations that you "check off" when they should be released. However if you have an index on "reservedto" and "reserved" the above second command would not be so bad.